# Anything equivalent to Rank-nullity theorem in infinite dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

By the well-known Rank-nullity theorem we have for a matrix, say, $A\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n)$,

$$ A \text{ is not injective}~\Longleftrightarrow~A \text{ is not surjective}$$

I remember (but I might be mistaken) that this holds true also for general linear operators $A:D(A)\rightarrow X$ in infinite-dimensional space which are Fredholm operators. Is this true, and if yes, why?

Comment: It is not true for arbitrary Fredholm operators. It is, basically by definition, true for Fredholm operators of index $0$. It is also true for self-adjoint operators with closed range.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any standard results on this in the literature?

Comment: Let $R:\ell^2(\Bbb N)\to\ell^2(\Bbb N)$ denote the right-shift, this is injective but not surjective while being Fredholm. Its adjoint, the left-shift, is surjective but not injective. If a bounded operator has closed range you have $im(A)=\ker(A^*)^\perp$, and so injective self-adjoints with closed range are surjective and the reverse is also true.